# Does using a Laravel Passport auth server and a separate resource server mean that there will always be two requests made?

Tags: laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Let`s assume this scenario ... you make a request to the auth server and it returns an access_token and this token will be sent in the header of all subsequent requests to the resource server.

Now for example, I want to get the list of friends for user X. I make the request to the resource server and the first thing that happens here is that it makes another request to the auth server in order to validate the access_token. If the validation is successful, a query is made to fetch the data from the db and the data is returned.

And this is where I get confused. This flow doesn`t seem right to me, because for every request to the resource server you have to make another request to the auth server in order the verify the access_token. Is this the correct flow ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type of setup you have so I might be wrong but the answer is probably no.

The auth service needs access to the access token storage to check if the token you are sending is valid or not. This is usually a db or cache. There's no way around this.

However, if you store your credentials in a totally separate system (like are remote server) then yeah, you might need another round trip. However, unless you really need to do this for some reason, this is highly inefficient.